# Converting to Mvc, ToolkitScriptManager ServiceReference

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajaxcontroltoolkit, webforms

So, I'm working in a hybrid web app/mvc application. Trying to do all new stuff in MVC and slowly changing some old webforms parts when there is time or a need for it. Using Razor.

Currently I'm trying to bring some old javascript into an mvc page and I'm having some troubles with the ServiceReferences. Is there a way to get these working in Razor, I really don't want to have to re-write this js file, seems how it's about 1500 lines.

I've got references to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/2.0/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
```

I'm guessing there must be some way to write this registration somewhere?
In webForms it worked like this, for reference:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="cnvScriptManager" EnablePartialRendering="true" ScriptMode="Release" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true" CombineScripts="true" CombineScriptsHandlerUrl="~/CombineScriptsHandler.ashx" runat="server">
                <Services>
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/util.asmx" />
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/menu/menu.asmx" />
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/menu/list.asmx" />
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/menu/tag.asmx" />
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/canvas/filter/filter.asmx" />
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/canvas/export/export.asmx" />
                </Services>
            </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

and then in the js you could do this nonsensical magic:

```
Xyz.Api.ListUXService.Fill(listParams, onFillListSuccess, onFailure, List);
```

I would love to have the time to convert it to jQuery and MVC, but, I don't :)

Comment: solved my problem, with an awesome hack I made up that I would never recommend anyone use, can't answer my own question though, until 8 hours from 36 minutes ago. Will post it tomorrow or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your razor view add a reference to a partial view, this partial view should be made with the webforms view engine

```
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_ScriptManager")
</body>
```

and then just put your scriptmanager in said partial view

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ajaxtoolkit:toolkitscriptmanager id="myScriptManager" enablepartialrendering="true"
    scriptmode="Release" loadscriptsbeforeui="true" combinescripts="true" combinescriptshandlerurl="~/CombineScriptsHandler.ashx"
    runat="server">
                <Services>
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/util.asmx" />
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/menu/list.asmx" />
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/menu/tag.asmx" />
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ux/controls/canvas/dialogs.asmx" />
                </Services>
</ajaxtoolkit:toolkitscriptmanager>
</form>
```

Now before all the mvc purists get mad, I want to add that I do not recommend doing this, this goes against MVC, but it works and if you don't have time to change a ton of legacy code, here is a solution.